# Why is it “I better not (+verb)” instead of “I better don’t (+verb)”?

Tags: etymology, idioms, sentence-patterns

This question will seem weird to a native speaker because “I better don’t” sounds inherently wrong and unusual. But if you think about it, it’s an irregularity; normally when a verb is negated and there is no auxiliary already present, the auxiliary “do” is inserted and usually contracted with the “not” to form “don’t”. The exceptional construct “I better not” baffles some non-native speakers.

What is the etymological history behind the construction “I better not (+verb)”? Did this sentence use to contain an auxiliary which has disappeared?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full phrase is *I had better* or *I'd better,* and it has a rather obscure and interesting history. It seems to be derived from an Old English phrase like *betera me**, literally *better to me* and having the meaning *it would be better for me.*

The object *me* changed to the subject *I,* and *had* showed up in the phrase some time in the Middle English period. This probably arose by association with *I would better,* which is why it's always *had* and not a present or other form of *to have.* As other answers have mentioned, where in Old English it took the infinitive, the phrase now takes the subjunctive, hence *I'd better go,* not *I'd better to go.*

Note that *best* may be used as well: *I (had) best avoid rattlesnakes.*

*I don't know how to inflect this.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the full form is "I **had** better not [do something]" - but the "had" is sometimes dropped in colloquial language.

[source](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/hadbetter/menu.php)

Comment: I actually thought of that, but somehow I find that explanation unsatisfactory because it introduces a past tense where semantically there is none, which raises the immediate question where *that* came from... You wouldn’t happen to be able to provide any reference/citations for this origin?

Comment: @Timwi: *had better* is simply an idiomatic expression and the auxiliary *had* in there is not the past tense. Rather, it implies the subjunctive. As to where that came from, you *might* (there's no past tense here, either!) want to check out this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/had-better-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-grammatically).

Answer (score 2):

As romkyns mentioned, the full form of the phrase is "I had better not". In this case "had" is not past tense, it's actually the subjunctive mood of the the phrase.

Think of the phrase "Were I to do this". In this case, "were" is not the imperfect of to be (as in "They were playing") but rather an indication of a subjunctive phrase.

In the same respect, "had" is not past tense of to have, it is a subjunctive indicator. If you take out "better", the phrase would become "I should not".

Comment: No, it would become “I have not (+verb)”, which is perfect tense. So the question where this came from still stands... :/