# Is the "hand't we" in "hadn't we better have a process?" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Consider this question:

> Is the "hand't we" in "hadn't we better have a process?" grammatical?

Is that correct? I am not sure if the use of the phrase "hadn't we better" is correct or not.

Comment: Related: [“Had better” — what is the meaning of this grammatically?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/had-better-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-grammatically)

Answer (score 1):

In UK English at least, it's absolutely fine and would be the usual question form of "we'd better have...".

Answer (score 0):

**Hadn't we better** is about strong opinions,

> Hadn't you better ask him first?

You had better ask him first.
Had better: should ask him, The speaker wants you to seek his advice.

**Had better** meaning: ought to.  don't omit the verb HAD:

> We HAD BETTER go home.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am off the mark, but I would suggest that a better way to express what you are trying to convey would be:

> "Shouldn't we have a process?"

rather than

> "Hadn't we better have a process?"

I believe both are acceptable, but the latter sounds a bit more like slang or a colloquial way of asking the question. Personally, I've used both, though I find that I use the "shouldn't" form more now than I used to. Matter of taste, perhaps?